# Get selected item from picker | SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to get the selected item from a Picker to update some data on the Firebase Database, but when i use the `onTapGesture` is not working

**Note:** The items inside the picker are Strings

**My Code:**

```
            Picker(selection: $numUnitIndex, label: Text("Numerical Unit: \(numUnit)")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< units.count) {
                    Text(self.units[$0]).tag($0).foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            //updateUnit(newUnit: self.units[numUnitIndex])
                            print("selected \(numUnitIndex)")
                        }
                }
            }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example of right way of doing this, no need `onTapGesture` here:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let units: [String] = ["", "", "", "", ""]
    @State private var selectedUnit: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedUnit, label: Text("You selected: \(units[selectedUnit])")) {
            ForEach(units.indices, id: \.self) { unitIndex in Text(units[unitIndex]) }
        }
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .onChange(of: selectedUnit, perform: { newValue in print("Selected Unit: \(units[newValue])", "Selected Index: \(newValue)")})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but before accept your Answer, can you put the PickerStyle next to onChange because there is some problems in UI if you add the OnChange after PickerStyle, thanks for your time :-)

Comment: @GSepetadelis: You are welcome. you can do that it make no deference!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use indices but the objects in the array in your ForEach and there is no need for onTapGesture, the variable passed to `selection` will hold the selected value.

Something like this

```
let units: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
@State private var selectedUnit: String

init() {
    selectedUnit = units.first ?? ""
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Picker("Units", selection: $selectedUnit) {
            ForEach(units, id: \.self) { unit in
                Text(unit)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        Text("Selected unit is \(selectedUnit)")
    }
}
```